# git revert is failing

Tags: git, github

i am trying to revert a commit but getting this error:

```
error: commit c89902d4bda1937ebb30c265758996c478f4bafa is a merge but no -m option was given.
```

fatal: revert failed

Not sure what to do. Please help.

Comment: Please take a few moments and search the site before you post a question.

Answer (score 0):

To revert a merge commit you need to specify `--mainline parent-number` or `-m parent-number`, can you try the following command:

```
git revert -m1 <commit-id>
```

Comment: do i need to repush my branch to github after this command?

Comment: If you wish to update remote branch then you have to push the code. Since above command revert the commit in your local only.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert). It is the best source for git help.